# Change Homebrew Cache

Tags: macos, npm, homebrew

I am using MacintheCloud paytogo plan.

I try to install vs-mda-remote tools with this tutorial.

[Tutorial MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858446.aspx)

It says i need no admin access.

Now it comes to some errors installing homebrew dependecies.
A few i could sort out with adding folder manually.

Now i facing the error Permission Denied /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula.

I know i can change this Path to some Folder where i have the rights, but how do i do this?

Couldn't find any helps to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the cache directory with the environment variable `HOMEBREW_CACHE`.  See the `brew` man page.